# How to implement Portrait In Picture Mode in Agora Android

Tags: android, android-studio, agora.io, agora, agora-implementation

I am currently working on an interactive live streaming project using the Agora platform for Android. I have successfully implemented virtual background features, such as setting background color, blur, or using an image, following the instructions provided in the official documentation here: [Agora Virtual Background Documentation.](https://docs.agora.io/en/interactive-live-streaming/enable-features/virtual-background?platform=android)

I have explored the provided documentation, but it does not contain specific guidance on implementing a **"portrait in picture"** mode.

**My question is:**

1. How can I implement a "portrait in picture" mode using Agora Virtual Background?
2. Are there any additional resources or examples available that can help me achieve this?
3. Are there any specific settings or configurations that need to be adjusted to achieve portrait mode with virtual background?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, code examples, or guidance from the community or anyone experienced with the Agora platform. Thank you in advance for your help!